JieLi Tech AC6955F4 BlueTooth IC Programming
I am experimenting with the AC6955F4 BlueTooth receiver IC from Jieli Tech (datasheet here: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2406031523_JieLi-Tech-AC6955F4_C22440783.pdf).
There is a repository on GitHub that documents someone's investigation of the AC6905 device which seems very similar:
https://github.com/christian-kramer/JieLi-AC690X-Familiarization
I designed the AC6955 into a PCB design based on some reference schematics I found (can be posted here if necessary, but I really don't think it's pertinent to my question).
When I plug my board into the USB port on my computer, the device is recognized correctly as "BR23 UBOOT1.00 USB Device" (which shows up as a Disk Drive in the Device Manager of Windows 7, and shows up as a removable disk under "Computer").


However, if I try to interact with Removable Disk (E:) in any way (opening it, or dragging a .bin file from the GitHub repo into it), it says "Please insert a disk into Removable Disk (E:)"
The Bluetooth chip itself does not appear to be programmed from the factory to function as a receiver (I assumed this would be the case).
While the writer of the GitHub repo supposes that the chip is programmed over the USB port using a pseudo-I2C protocol (data written on falling edge of the clock signal), he does not seem to ever get the blank device programmed and working as a Bluetooth receiver (see the end of the README.md file):
https://github.com/christian-kramer/JieLi-AC690X-Familiarization/blob/master/README.md
I have the JieLi BT Configuration Tool 2.1.0.4 (downloaded from that GitHub repo), but have no idea exactly how to use it:

I know there is an Arduino sketch which the writer created, but that seems to send a fixed string of data and that's it. I am thinking that is not what I need here. Does anyone here have experience with these devices and programming them to function as BlueTooth receivers?
PROGRESS SO FAR:
With the (very much appreciated!) help from Chester Gillon, I seem to have gotten further in the process. I downloaded the SDK from the following link:
https://gitlab.zh-jieli.com/soundbox/novisualization/ac695n_soundbox_sdk
The directory, "cpu/br23/tools" brings me to an executable file titled "isd_download.exe". Running this executable brings up a command prompt in Windows:

Once within the command prompt, I entered "open E:" (remember, E: is the drive letter that popped up when I plugged in my board to my computer) and it opened successfully. At this point, however, I am still attempting to determine how to load the firmware (presumably "br23loader.bin") onto the device. I attempted to use "wd \br23loader.bin" but had no success. It thinks that the path and filename of "br23loader.bin" is another command, and it is not recognizing it as a file.
UPDATE #2:
As far as I can tell, "br23loader.bin" is, in fact, not the firmware file. Instead, it expects a ".fw" or ".fwu" file here. It seems I am still missing some vital information. I was really hoping there was a prepackaged program that could simply give me the basic Bluetooth receiver functionality that I could load onto this device, but it is proving quite difficult. Further thoughts and ideas are greatly appreciated!

My reading of the github README linked in the question is that you need to run isd_download.exe -dev br23 on Windows, to program a firmware file named br23loader.bin.
Where the br23 part is based upon the device enumerating as "BR23 UBOOT1.00 USB Device".
Searching found a gitlab ac695n_soundbox_sdk / cpu / br23 / tools which contains among others the following files which look relevant to attempt to program the firmware from a Windows PC:

br23loader.bin
isd_download.exe

I don't have a chip to verify if the above files will work, but suggest investigate their use.
The gitlib repository appears to contain a software development kit for the ac695n series of ICs. The sample of documentation I looked at was in Chinese (simplified), but online translation tools should help.

I downloaded isd_download.exe from the gitlab repository and in Windows 11 64-bit:

Scanned it using Windows Defender - no threats found
Ran it with no arguments, and it reported usage:
C:\Users\mr_halfword\Downloads>isd_download.exe
Usage:
      open <device name: eg:[ f:\ | \device\harddiskvolume8]> - open device
      close -  close device
      ds - show disk status
      st - set device type
      wr <type:1-flash 7-otp> <sdram file> [address] - download sdram to device and run it
      wd <firmware file> [address] - download firmware to device flash
      ed <address> <length> - erase device flash
      help
      quit




This is very promising, thanks for pointing out that part! Unfortunately Windows 7 is telling me that "isd_download.exe" is incompatible with my machine (it's 32-bit software, whereas my OS is 64-bit). Compatibility mode is not helping

Ok, I found a newer version of isd_download.exe that does not seem to have this issue. Unfortunately I think I'm still missing a step, so I will keep investigating

@DerStrom8 I updated the answer to record was able to run isd_download.exe under Windows 11 64-bit. The first time clicked "save as" and got a HTML file. The second time clicked on the file in the gitlab repository and then clicked on "Download", and got the exe which ran.

Thanks! I was eventually able to download and run the software and got the same menu as you, but I seem to be struggling to find out how to actually connect it to the device plugged into the USB port. Based on the menu, I need to first open the device using the "open" command, but the example they provide of the Device Name is confusing

@DerStrom8 Try using the drive letter for the "Disk Drive" which shows up when the plug the board in. E.g. based upon what in shown in the question isd_download.exe open E:\\

So, trying to run from the command line does not seem to work - my screen glitches and it acts like it's opening a bunch of CMD windows, but ultimately I end up right back at the original CMD window and nothing happened. I can run the EXE directly and that's where I get the menu. However, trying to run any of the commands gives me an error saying something about FLASH ID not being set in isd_tools.cfg. I opened the .cfg file and noticed it was calling out the AF6901, so I'm trying a different download

Ok, was able to get it to open successfully! Now I need to figure out what firmware to install and how. I do not see "dev" as a command, but I do see a couple of "write" commands. Unfortunately they seem to be looking for addresses, and I don't think I came across any of that in the datasheet or documentation at all

@DerStrom8 The help text wd <firmware file> [address] having the address in square brackets suggests the address is optional. I.e. you could try wd br23loader.bin to try writing the firmware file using the default address. Since the number of comments is increasing, you could start creating your own answer and fill in the steps taken and the results.

You're right - I will update my post with the steps we have followed to this point. In the meantime, simply typing "wd br23loader.bin" returns an error that "br23loader.bin" is an unknown command. I wondered if it was looking for a full file path, but unfortunately my path has spaces (not my fault!) and it seems to treat each section of the path as a separate command, even when enclosed in quotes

it seems like it may be expecting a ".fw" file, not a ".bin" file, but I can't be sure. I still have no clue how the "isd_download.exe" tool is supposed to work. I have found references to "uboot.boot" being a bootloader, and perhaps the "br23loader.bin" is supposed to be used with the bootloader. Haven't figured out how to use the bootloader tool yet though
